# set post_type based on custom taxonomy permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type registered as `publication` and a custom taxonomy registered as `publication_category`.

The post type's slug is `publication` and the taxonomy slug is `publication/category`.

The reason I have it set up like that is to get these urls

```
example.com/publication/ - Archive
example.com/publication/post-name - Single
example.com/publication/category/category-name - Category Archive
```

The problem is that when I go to this url `example.com/publication/category/category-name` the post_type is not set so it uses the default archive template.

Is there a way without passing in `?post_type=publication` that I can set the post_type to publication so it uses the publication archive template?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the post_type was being set but for some reason it would not load the appropriate archive template.  I'm suspect it has something to do with the way my post type and custom taxonomy are set up.

Here is a solution I came up with.  I'm open to suggestions.

```
function custom_template_redirect() {
    if (is_archive() && get_post_type() != '') {
        $file = TEMPLATEPATH . '/archive-' . get_post_type() . '.php';
        if ( file_exists( $file ) ) {
            include ($file);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_template_redirect');
```